# How to get the value of a selected text in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the selected value of dropdownlist using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript)

I have a select:

```
<select id="short_code">
<option value="12">First</option>
<option value="11">Second</option>
<option value="10">Third</option>
<option value="9">Fourth</option>    
</select>
```

I want to get the value of the selected text. e.g. if the selected text is `First` so the I need to get `12`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getSelected(select) {
        alert(select.options[select.selectedIndex].value);
    }
</script>    

<select id="short_code" onchange="getSelected(this)">    
    <option value="12">First</option>
    <option value="11">Second</option>
    <option value="10">Third</option>
    <option value="9">Fourth</option>    
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById('short_code').value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('short_code').options[document.getElementById('short_code').selectedIndex].text
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var el = document.getElementById("short_code");
var code = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
```