# Get the option value in select in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the selected value of dropdownlist using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript)
>   [How to get the value of a selected text in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828125/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-selected-text-in-javascript)

```
<select id="short_code">
<option value="12">First</option>
<option value="11">Second</option>
<option value="10">Third</option>
<option value="9">Fourth</option>    
</select>
```

I need to do this:

```
if(document.getElementById("short_code").options.item(document.getElementById("short_code").selectedIndex).text)== "First")

//get the value of the option Fist , how to get the value?
```

Comment: You [just asked about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828125/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-selected-text-in-javascript). If the answers don't work, you need to clarify your question instead of reposting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var elem = document.getElementById("short_code"),
    selectedNode = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex];

if ( selectedNode.value === "First" ) { //...
```

Comment: This isn't *really* how you'd do this, is it? It's a long (and potentially error prone) way of doing `elem.options[elem.selectedIndex]`.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I missed the joke.

Comment: selectedNode = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
var select = document.getElementById('short_code');
var options = select.options;
var selected = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
//which means that:
console.log(selected.value || selected.getAttribute('value'));//should log "12"
console.log(selected.innerHTML);//should log(First);
```

Loop through all the options (either creating a reference variable, like I did with `options`, or plain `for (var i=0;i<select.options.length;i++)`) and you can get all info you need

Comment: `either creating a reference variable, like I did with options, or plain for ` - You didn't use it though....

Comment: No, I didn't, but I included it in the snippet just to show how to reference a nodes list